# What are the 19 gifts of the Spirit, as listed by Leslie Flynn?

Tags: new-testament, pneumatology, reference-request, spiritual-gifts, books

I recently heard a preacher say there are 19 gifts of the Spirit.  That specific number seems to derive from [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1564763374) by Leslie Flynn.  Most lists, including even those that reference this book, tend to list 16 gifts ([example](http://linnproductions.com/clients/bfcrc/uploads/spiritual_gifts.pdf)), but I did find [one list](http://www.viewpointchristianchurch.org/phocadownload/The%20Gifts%20of%20the%20Holy%20Spirit.pdf) with 21 gifts.  I was unable to locate Flynn's list, however.  What are the 19 gifts, as defined by Flynn?

Comment: Interesting. Catholics and I believe Orthodox recognize 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the table of contents of the [book you linked to](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1564763374)*, the 19 are:

1. The Apostolic Gift
2. Prophecy
3. Evangelism
4. Shepherding
5. Teaching
6. Exhortation
7. Knowledge
8. Wisdom
9. Helps
10. Hospitality
11. Giving
12. Government
13. Showing Mercy
14. Faith
15. Discernment
16. Miracles
17. Healing
18. Tongues
19. Interpretation

*To see the list yourself, click on the link to the amazon product listing, click the book cover, then click the link for the table of contents.

Comment: Thanks.  I did "look inside" at Amazon, but somehow missed the TOC.